# configure Unix apache Web server to automatically start on reboot?

Tags: centos, rhel, apache-httpd, startup

How you would configure a Unix Web server to automatically start on reboot?

Webserver- apache Web server
os-centos
Using Wget command I have downloaded the apache  Web server.

For example In Windows, for the same situation I would install the apache tomcat with windows service. And in services I mark the run config as automatically. So that for if main windows server gets reboot. The apache tomcat will automatically gets up and run.

I need to achieve this in redhat and centos with apache webserver

Comment: Almost all webservers will automatically start based on the service manager of host linux; what is your situation exactly? which server? which ubuntu? did you installed from repository?

Comment: If it's correctly installed from Centos packages, they should already include a script which starts it when the system boots. If you compiled it from source yourself, you need to deploy the integration scripts yourself as well.

Comment: Depending upon the RHEL version, it is either `chkconfig httpd on` or `systemctl enable httpd` to make it automatically start on reboot. Assuming they were installed via yum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand your question since it is written quite poorly but I'll try to help.

Run the following code to enable the httpd service to run on startup

```
sudo systemctl enable httpd
```

Run the following code to start the httpd service this time since it hasn't been probably activated yet

```
sudo systemctl start httpd
```